# How to use QLThumbnailImageCreate with CGPDFPageRef not a CFURLRef

Tags: pdf, thumbnails, nsimage

QLThumbnailImageCreate requires a CFURLRef as an argument.  Is there some way to concoct a CFURLRef for a CGPDFPageRef?  I could write the CGPDFPageRef to a file, then use that URL.  It's ugly but would work.  Is there a better way?

EDIT:
HERE I FILL AN ARRAY (repArray) WITH PAGE IMAGES CREATED IN A BITMAP CONTEXT:

```
    CGContextRef pdfContext = MyCreateBitmapContext(width,height);  
    CGPDFPageRef pageRef = CGPDFDocumentGetPage (myDocument, index);
    NSImage* anImage;
    @try
    {
        CGContextDrawPDFPage (pdfContext,pageRef );
        CGImageRef ref = (CGBitmapContextCreateImage (pdfContext));
        anImage = [[NSImage alloc]initWithCGImage:ref size:NSZeroSize];

        [repArray addObject:anImage];
    }
```

...

HERE I CONCATONATE THE IMAGES TO MAKE ONE LONG IMAGE:

```
    NSImage* outImage = [[NSImage alloc]initWithSize:NSMakeSize(pageSize.width,(pageSize.height +    10)*numberOfPages)];
    [outImage lockFocus];
    NSRect sourceRect = NSMakeRect(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height);
    NSImage* pageImage;
    NSInteger maxH = (pageSize.height + 10)*numberOfPages;
    NSInteger unitH = pageSize.height + 10;
    for (NSInteger index = 0; index < numberOfPages; index++)
    {
        pageImage = [repArray objectAtIndex:index];
        NSPoint pt = NSMakePoint(0, maxH - (index + 1) * unitH);
        [pageImage drawAtPoint:pt fromRect:sourceRect operation:NSCompositingOperationSourceOver fraction:1.0];
    }
    [outImage unlockFocus];
    return outImage;
```

HERE I CREATE A CGContextRef USING APPLE'S CODE:

```
CGContextRef MyCreateBitmapContext (int pixelsWide, int pixelsHigh)
    {
    CGContextRef    context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    void *          bitmapData;
    int             bitmapByteCount;
    int             bitmapBytesPerRow;

    bitmapBytesPerRow   = (pixelsWide * 4);// 1
    bitmapByteCount     = (bitmapBytesPerRow * pixelsHigh);

    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericRGB);// 2
    bitmapData = calloc(pixelsHigh, bitmapBytesPerRow );// 3
    if (bitmapData == NULL)
    {
        fprintf (stderr, "Memory not allocated!");
        return NULL;
    }
    context = CGBitmapContextCreate (bitmapData,
                                 pixelsWide,
                                 pixelsHigh,
                                 8,
                                 bitmapBytesPerRow,
                                 colorSpace,
                                 kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
     if (context== NULL)
    {
        free (bitmapData);// 5
        fprintf (stderr, "Context not created!");
        return NULL;
    }
    CGColorSpaceRelease( colorSpace );// 6

    return context;// 7
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is your goal? Do you just want a small image of the PDF page? In that case, you can just draw the PDF page to a Core Graphics bitmap context and then create an image from the context. You would set up the context's transformation matrix to get the desired scaling.

Comment: My goal is a series of full page size NSImages stacked into a single long image. I currently can do that as you suggest. See above.  It's too pixelated.  As I use Quick-Look for other kinds of files, I thought I'd  try QL.  I'd be happy to modify the bitmap approach, but I don't know enough about it.  Any suggestions?